# Client side filter show all items when all checkboxes have been deselected

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tags

Onload the check boxes are unchecked and the all list items are displayed.
When a filter is checked on the those list items relating are be displayed.
The problem i am having is when you uncheck all of the checkboxes again i need all items to show rather than hide.

Here's my fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/amesy/B9Hnu/124/

```
$(function() {

var $checkboxes = $("input[id^='type-']");
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').attr('checked', false);

$checkboxes.change(function() {
    var selector = '';
    $checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() { // checked 
        selector += '.' + this.id.replace('type-', '') + ', ';
        // builds a selector like '.A, .B, .C, ' 
    });
    selector = selector.substring(0, selector.length - 2); // remove trailing ', '
    $('#list li').hide() // hide all rows
    .filter(selector).show(); // reduce set to matched and show
});

});
```

Ultimately this will be used in a portfolio but I will be splitting the filters/tags up into their categories. If anyone wants to advise it would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/B9Hnu/125/

```
if( $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length<=0)
{
//show all
}
else{

// your logic
}
```

Comment: Thanks :)
i just created a new question based on the next stage if you up for answering it :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063529/client-side-filtering-using-jquery