# Client side filtering using jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, filtering

So this fiddle which doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/1auhde3L/ is based on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/B9Hnu/125/ which does work, but it doesn't take into account how my html is set out using data-category and the tags in the rel or ID tags of the checkboxes.

here's the jquery...

```
$(function() {

var $checkboxes = $("input[id^='type-']");
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').attr('checked', false);

$checkboxes.change(function() {
    console.log($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length);
    if( $('input[type=checkbox]:checked'
         ).length>0)
{
    var selector = '';
    $checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() { // checked 
        //selector += '.' + this.id.replace('type-', '') + ', ';
        selector += "[data-category~='" + element.id + "']";                  
        // builds a selector like '.A, .B, .C, ' 
    });
    selector = selector.substring(0, selector.length - 2); // remove trailing ', '
    $('.results > div').hide() // hide all rows
    .filter(selector).show(); // reduce set to matched and show
}else

{
 $('.results > div').show()    
}
 });

});
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Here is my previous question based on the same project i'm working on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27061828/client-side-filter-show-all-items-when-all-checkboxes-have-been-deselected

trying to make a multiple filtering system using WordPress tags as the filters. the tags will be split up into 3 categories (Service, Clients and Section).

For the moment i'm just trying to get the flittering to work on an AND so that all displayed will contain all the tags that are selected which the initial fiddle does, but using my html in the second fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are [looking for](http://jsfiddle.net/1auhde3L/45/).

There were a few issues in your code:

1. You are looking for `$("input[id^='type-']");` but the problem is that your id's don't start with "type-"
2. I modified your code to also add a second selector otherwise you would not show elements because of the order in which the check box was selected. For instance - if you click email and then branding - your selector will have the string email branding and it will not select the div with the data-category of "branding email". The other way you might want to consider is to create an array and use that to filter instead.

Happy coding!

UPDATE

---

I [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/1auhde3L/58/) the code to use an array instead of a string. This will allow you to filter based on the individual strings. It also eliminates the order in which your checkboxes are clicked and it eliminates the needs for two selector strings.

Comment: Thanks Gjohn, this is great! i may go down the array route yet as this is evolving while i'm trying to make it as efficient as possible.

Comment: i've just noticed that if the tags aren't in teh same order as they are in the checkboxes then the item will not display http://jsfiddle.net/1auhde3L/45/

Comment: so if you select all checkboxes, number 7 should still display, but it doesn't